# Emacs "M-x term" Prompt

Tags: emacs, editor, elisp

When I start a terminal in Emacs 23.3.1 it prompts me with "Run program: /usr/local/bin/bash".  How can I get rid of this prompt?  I would like to bind F4 to starting a terminal without it prompting me for the same shell every time.

Something like:

```
(global-set-key [f4] 'term)
```

This doesn't work though.  It will start a terminal, but it still prompts me to enter the shell again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(global-set-key [f4] '(lambda () (interactive) (term (getenv "SHELL"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like using terms in emacs, you could look at [multi term](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.fr/2010/06/console-apps-in-emacs-with-multi-term.html).